# Breaker keeps tripping after replaced

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

My garage breaker tripped out of no where about a week ago while we were at work. It kept tripping after resetting it. The wire goes underground from the panel and into the garage.

At the first junction box it splits and one line goes to an outdoor gfci and the other supplies power to the rest of the garage via a receptacle. I disconnected those junctions so nothing was connected and the breaker immediately tripped which made me assume the breaker went bad.

I replaced the breaker and checked for loose neutrals. Turned the power back on. Reconnected the first junction and receptacle. All was good. Plugged in a google speaker and nothing else. A little while later the breaker tripped.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be great! This is stumping me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it? Also, is the underground wiring directly buried, or is the run in conduit all the way to the garage?

Comment: No test button on the breaker. I assume it is a buried wire without pipe because it is a gray wrapped wiring. Not THHN.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the labeling on that grey wrapped wiring, and does that wrapped wiring extend all the way into the ground...?

Comment: I just updated some pics. So far the breaker hasn’t tripped since that first time after replacing the breaker. Almost 24hrs ago.